# Operator = is not a member of exported C++ __interface in DLL

Tags: c++, dll, interface, c++11

I have been writing some code for a lib and experimented with a default Win32 console application to get everything running. Since I have completed all classes I wanted to extract everything into a DLL and therefore I started the adaptation with the usual macro:

```
#ifdef MYLIB_EXPORTS
    #define DllExport __declspec(dllexport)
#else
    #define DllExport __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
```

I am using one interface in my code which is defined like this:

```
__interface DllExport ISerializable {
    void Serialize(/* ... */);
    /* some other methods */
};
```

And this has worked while gaving this code in my exe. In the DLL I get an error during compilation which states

```
error C2039: '=' : is not a member of 'MyLib::ISerializable'
error C2664: 'MyLib::DerivedClass::operator =' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const MyLib::ISerializable' to 'const MyLib::DerivedClass &'
```

for every class which inherits `ISerializable` to implement the required methods. (I am using `std::shared_ptr<ISerializable>` a few times to have abstraction in my code.) However when I change `__interface` to `class` and make all methods pure virtual I do not get this error and compilation succeeds.

**Why do I get this error? Why does my class/interface in my DLL need the assignment operator? Is there any workaround?**

*(Using Visual Studio 2012 RTM on Windows 8 RTM with C++11.)*

---

Here is one segment where this error occurs (error point always to the last `}` of the class):

```
class DllExport Tile final : public ISerializable {
public:
    __declspec(property(get=GetIsPassable, put=SetIsPassable))
    bool IsPassable;
    __declspec(property(get=GetTileId, put=SetTileId))
    uint16_t TileId;

    bool& GetIsPassable() { return this->_IsPassable; }
    void SetIsPassable(bool val) { this->_IsPassable = val; }
    uint16_t& GetTileId() { return this->_TileId; }
    void SetTileId(uint16_t val) { this->_TileId = val; }

    bool _IsPassable;
    uint16_t _TileId;

    void Serialize(OutputFileStream& ofs);
    size_t TellSize();
    size_t Unserialize(InputFileStream& ifs, size_t metadata = 0);
};
```

This error also occurs in a class where I have a property like in the `Tile` class where I use a `std::shared_ptr<ISerializable>`.

Comment: Based on the error message, I would say your problem has nothing to do with DLLs or `dllexport`/`dllimport`.

Comment: This exact code of the interface worked when having it directly in a usual Win32 Console Project. This error occurs since having the code in a DLL project.

Comment: An interface doesn't have a copy constructor or assignment operator like a class does.  One abstraction too many perhaps.  Post the actual code that fails to compile.

Comment: @HansPassant: Added the code you requested.

Comment: Why does the question ask about "the operator to compare two objects"?  In C++, `operator=` is assignment, not comparison.

Comment: @Hans: I don't think that's the issue.  From the error message, the code that's failing is `var_of_derived_type = expression_of_interface_type;`, which requires a conversion.  It's not a copy assignment.

Comment: The suggestion to explocitly implement `DerivedClass::operator=` by the new user who answered this question two times works. Is there a more elegant way to do so rather than having to type all the `operator=` for each class the compiler is complaining?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess interfaces don't have compiler-generated copy constructors or assignment operators.

One possible solution is to explicitly implement `DerivedClass::operator=`. That's because the compiler-generated version will try to call `ISerializable::operator=`, which doesn't exist. Same thing for copy constructors.

Another solution is to make all your classes COM classes :)

---

**Example**

Using your Tile class:

```
class DllExport Tile final : public ISerializable { 
public: 
    Tile(const Tile& tile) :
        _IsPassable(tile._IsPassable), _TileId(tile._TileId)
    {
    }

    /* New Code START */
    Tile& operator=(const Tile& tile)
    {
        _IsPassable = tile._IsPassable;
        _TileId = tile._TileId;
        return *this;
    }
    /* New Code END */

    __declspec(property(get=GetIsPassable, put=SetIsPassable)) 
    bool IsPassable; 
    __declspec(property(get=GetTileId, put=SetTileId)) 
    uint16_t TileId; 

    bool& GetIsPassable() { return this->_IsPassable; } 
    void SetIsPassable(bool val) { this->_IsPassable = val; } 
    uint16_t& GetTileId() { return this->_TileId; } 
    void SetTileId(uint16_t val) { this->_TileId = val; } 

    bool _IsPassable; 
    uint16_t _TileId; 

    void Serialize(OutputFileStream& ofs); 
    size_t TellSize(); 
    size_t Unserialize(InputFileStream& ifs, size_t metadata = 0); 
};
```

Comment: Could you please provide sample code what it does look like to have `DerivedClass::operator=` correctly implemented?

Comment: You could have edited your originale answer and add the code there - please do so to keep this structured and clean. Nevertheless I will try out your code.

Comment: Your code works when applied to every class the compiler complains. I would like to see a more elegant version if possible to avoid repeating the assigments. - Furthermore I have edited this answer (changes pending) and requested a merge of both your answers, however a mod must do this.

Comment: Actually you don't need to explicitly reimplement all operators and constructors that the C++ compiler implements itself. Note that often **operator=** must be written explicitly because the default implementation is not good. But if you want to leave it for compiler, you should cause the compiler to generate this operator. Your DLL must contain at least one usage of this operator. E.g. add a dummy method to your class which *uses* the **operator=**

Comment: operator= is generated automatically for classes and structs, but not for interfaces. That's why an explicit operator= was needed here, because the default one would try to call the inherited interface's operator=, which doesn't exist.